# Using COALESCE, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY GROUPING Issue in MySQL-SOLVED

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table which shows the frequencies of revenue per agent and team in weeks. I have used COALESCE, GROUP BY, AND ORDER BY GROUPING statements to generate the Total. My only issue is that it also copies the name of the team.

```
    COALESCE(sales_agent.name, '')AS Agent, 
    COALESCE(sales_team.name,  '')AS Team, 
    
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=1), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 1', 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=2), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 2', 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=3), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 3',
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=4), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 4',
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=5), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 5',
    SUM(product.price * line_item.quantity) AS Total
    
FROM ((((line_item
INNER JOIN order_ ON line_item.order_id = order_.order_id)
INNER JOIN sales_agent ON order_.agent_id = sales_agent.agent_id)
INNER JOIN sales_team ON sales_agent.team_id  = sales_team.team_id)
INNER JOIN product ON line_item.product_id = product.product_id)
GROUP BY sales_agent.name WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY GROUPING(sales_agent.name),sales_agent.agent_id;

The output:

+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| Agent  | Team  | Week 1  | Week 2  | Week 3  | Week 4  | Week 5  | Total    |
+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| Galpo  | Alpha | 1590.00 | 2130.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  3720.00 |
| Rosita | Bravo |    0.00 | 2410.00 | 1485.00 |    0.00 | 2455.00 |  6350.00 |
| Harry  | Alpha |    0.00 | 1745.00 |  815.00 | 1840.00 |    0.00 |  4400.00 |
| Erika  | Bravo |    0.00 | 2000.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  910.00 |  2910.00 |
|        | Bravo | 1590.00 | 8285.00 | 2300.00 | 1840.00 | 3365.00 | 17380.00 |
+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+

New table:

SELECT CONCAT(ranges.lo, ' - ', ranges.hi) AS Revenue,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM line_item
JOIN product USING (product_id)
JOIN ( SELECT    0 lo,  500 hi UNION
       SELECT  501   , 1000        UNION
       SELECT 1001   , 1500       UNION
       SELECT 1501   , 2000       UNION
       SELECT 2001   , 2500 ) ranges ON product.price * line_item.quantity BETWEEN ranges.lo AND ranges.hi
GROUP BY ranges.lo, ranges.hi

UNION ALL SELECT '',
(
    SELECT 
    COUNT(product.price * line_item.quantity)
    FROM (line_item
    INNER JOIN product ON line_item.product_id = product.product_id)
);
```

Comment: You should `GROUP BY agent, team`.

Comment: I did that but it creates a sub group for the team making the table much more complicated to look at. My only objective is to maintain the output of the table as it is except that the 'Bravo' word in the last row be removed.

Comment: Is there a case that an agent to belong in more than 1 teams?

Comment: No. there is not.

Comment: I have incorporated your answer as to the addition of GROUP BY agent, team and the result is updated in the view. It did remove the row Bravo in the last row of column team but have duplicated the array of agents as its compromise.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each Agent may belong to only 1 team, you don't need to group by team.
So change:

```
COALESCE(sales_team.name,  '') AS Team
```

to:

```
CASE WHEN GROUPING(sales_agent.agent_id) = 0 THEN COALESCE(MAX(sales_team.name), '') END AS Team
```

Also you should use the agent's id also in the `GROUP BY` clause and set the conditions in the HAVING clause to display only the final totals:

```
GROUP BY sales_agent.agent_id, Agent WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(sales_agent.agent_id) = 1 OR GROUPING(Agent) = 0
ORDER BY GROUPING(sales_agent.agent_id), sales_agent.agent_id
```

So your query can be written:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(sales_agent.name, '')AS Agent, 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(sales_agent.agent_id) = 0 THEN COALESCE(MAX(sales_team.name), '') END AS Team, 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=1), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 1', 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=2), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 2', 
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=3), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 3',
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=4), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 4',
    SUM(IF((WEEK(order_.date) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(order_.date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(order_.date)-1 DAY)) + 1=5), product.price * line_item.quantity,0)) AS 'Week 5',
    SUM(product.price * line_item.quantity) AS Total
FROM line_item
INNER JOIN order_ ON line_item.order_id = order_.order_id
INNER JOIN sales_agent ON order_.agent_id = sales_agent.agent_id
INNER JOIN sales_team ON sales_agent.team_id  = sales_team.team_id
INNER JOIN product ON line_item.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY sales_agent.agent_id, Agent WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(sales_agent.agent_id) = 1 OR GROUPING(Agent) = 0
ORDER BY GROUPING(sales_agent.agent_id), sales_agent.agent_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4fc8f44a6a978b7308d993abba14f335).
Results:

```
> Agent  | Team  |  Week 1 |  Week 2 |  Week 3 |  Week 4 |  Week 5 |    Total
> :----- | :---- | ------: | ------: | ------: | ------: | ------: | -------:
> Galpo  | Alpha | 1590.00 | 2130.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  3720.00
> Rosita | Bravo |    0.00 | 2410.00 | 1485.00 |    0.00 | 2455.00 |  6350.00
> Harry  | Alpha |    0.00 | 1745.00 |  815.00 | 1840.00 |    0.00 |  4400.00
> Erika  | Bravo |    0.00 | 2000.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  910.00 |  2910.00
> null   | null  | 1590.00 | 8285.00 | 2300.00 | 1840.00 | 3365.00 | 17380.00
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224894/discussion-on-answer-by-forpas-using-coalesce-group-by-and-order-by-grouping-i).

Comment: No, this is a different requirement.

Comment: @forpas-I hope you can also do something to remove the NULL values in this table.

Comment: @toff What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: @forpas-Probably just blank or hyphen if it is possible.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f713a167ff5d81d3eac621ca34ae1bd but you have to no that `null` in any case will come empty in your app. It is shown as *null* in the fiddle as a notation of empty.

Comment: @forpas-Great solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224921/discussion-between-toff-and-forpas).